# Saving number of button clicks

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm working on a simple 'Click Countdown' application, which basically has an imagebutton 
function.

when pressed it displays the number of clicks from 10 to 9, 8, 7,... to 0.

I have a problem, when I close the application the number of clicks starts again from 
10.

I know that's quite beginner question, but can someone help me please? 

how can I save number of clicks?

This is the code I have so far:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import com.example.testapp.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton button1;
    TextView textView1;
    int counter = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        ImageButton imageButton;
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){



            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (counter >= 1) {
                    counter--;
                    textView1.setText("" + counter);
                } else if (counter == 0){
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2);
                    counter--;

                }


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: store it in a `sharedpreference` :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). They will allow you to save data between sessions:

E.g.

At startup:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
clickCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("Click_Count", 0);
```

Saving:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("Click_Count", clickCount);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your count value in SharedPreferences as follows...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (counter >= 1) {
        counter--;
        textView1.setText("" + counter);

        prefsEditor.putInt("counter", counter);
        prefsEditor.commit();

    } else if (counter == 0){
        button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2);
        counter--;

        prefsEditor.putInt("counter", counter);
        prefsEditor.commit();

    }
}
```

Retrieve that counter value from SharedPreferences as follows...

```
counter = prefs.getInt("counter", 10);
```

Now if it can't find value in SharedPreferences with the key "counter" then it will return a default value of 10.